# Are the proton and electron quantum entangled in the hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-entanglement, hydrogen

Do the proton and electron share the same wave function when describing a hydrogen atom?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by "*share the same wave function*".
But anyway:
The general solution of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation
for the hydrogen atom is a single wave function
$$\psi(\mathbf{r}_p, \mathbf{r}_e, t)$$
where $\mathbf{r}_p$ is the position of the proton
and $\mathbf{r}_e$ is the position of the electron.
There are convenient special solutions with a factorized form
$$\psi(\mathbf{r}_p, \mathbf{r}_e, t)=\psi_p(\mathbf{R}) \psi_e(\mathbf{r}) e^{-iEt/\hbar}$$
where $\mathbf{R}=\frac{m_p\mathbf{r}_p+m_e\mathbf{r}_e}{m_p+m_e}$
is the center-of-mass position
and $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}_e-\mathbf{r}_p$ is the position difference
between proton and electron.
But these are not the only possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that: if one could measure the spin of the electron, one would know the spin of the proton without measureing it because of the wavefunction describing the atom, the answer is yes.

Comment: For larger atoms, look at the [electron-nuclear spin interaction](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403122).